# Finding distance to nearest point from feature using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, proximity

In Google Earth Engine I have a FeatureCollection of 14,002 points. For each of the points I want to find the next nearest point's distance away. I don't need to record the nearest point ID, only the distance to it and save it in the feature. I haven't been able to find anything in the Docs that would do this.

Essentially I am trying to implement ArcMap's NEAR tool (found here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm 
into something similar in GEE but haven't found a way yet.

Answer (score 4):

It's a multi-step process, but can be done with a spatial join (see [this doc](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/joins_spatial)):

```js
var points = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(geometry, 14000, 0, 10);
Map.addLayer(points, {}, 'points')

// Max search distance is 5 km.
var spatialFilter = ee.Filter.withinDistance({
  distance: 5000,
  leftField: '.geo',
  rightField: '.geo',
  maxError: 10
})

// Join the points to themselves.
var joined = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'neighbors', 
  measureKey: 'distance',
  ordering: 'distance'
}).apply({
  primary: points, 
  secondary: points, 
  condition: spatialFilter
});

// Get rid of points w/o neighbors.
// Increase distance in the spatialFilter if
// you want them all to have neighbors.
var hasNearest = joined.map(function(f) {
  var neighsSize = ee.List(f.get('neighbors')).size();
  return f.set('neighsSize', neighsSize);
}).filter(ee.Filter.gt('neighsSize', 1));
Map.addLayer(hasNearest, {color: 'red'}, 'hasNearest');

// Get distance to nearest point.
var withNearestDist = hasNearest.map(function(f) {
  var nearestDist = ee.Feature(ee.List(f.get('neighbors')).get(1))
      .get('distance');
  return f.set('nearestDist', nearestDist);
});
Map.addLayer(withNearestDist, {color: 'blue'}, 'withNearestDist');
```

Note that you get all the neighbors, whether you want them or not.

Comment: How would you modify this if some of the points are stacked (e.g. have exactly the same lat/long) and therefore sometimes there are multiple nearest neighbors?  And also just return those nearest neighbors, not the others?  Thanks!

Comment: Here's the rough shape: You have all the neighbors (`f.get('neighbors')`) and their distances.  Call `distinct()` on those, get the smallest distance, get all the features with the smallest distance and then do something to them.

Comment: Thank you I did get that working in the way you suggested.  Question:  what if you wanted this interactive, so just wanted the nearest point to where someone clicked.  Is there a fast approach (using Map.getBounds() and buffer are quite slow with this many points like the Op has)